# reactJS - Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am fairly new to reactJS and I am trying to use bootstrap Modal like so:

```
class Footer extends Component {

  render() { 

    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

    return ( 

    <footer className="footer-bottom">
      <Container>
           <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
              Close
          </Button>
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
              Save Changes
          </Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
      </Container> 
     </footer>
  );
  }
}
```

However I am getting this error:

`Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`

My question is how do I turn my const (show, setShow, handleClose, handelShow) into a function to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Hooks can only be used in function components, so your component cannot extend React.Component.  Instead of this:

```
class Footer extends Component {
```

do this:

```
Footer = (props) => {

   //rest of the code 

}
```

Because you are now not extending the Component class, you don't need a render() function.  Just do a return from the Footer function instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the component you're making right now is a class component, not a function component. As of now, [hooks don't work inside classes](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#but-what-is-a-hook). Try changing your code to this:

```js
export default function Footer() {


    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

    return ( 

    <footer className="footer-bottom">
      <Container>
           <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
              Close
          </Button>
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
              Save Changes
          </Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
      </Container> 
     </footer>
  );
  
}
```

Comment: New error:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "(" on this: export default function Footer {

Comment: change the first line to this: export default function Footer(props) {

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the parenthesis

Comment: New error:  Parsing error: Only one default export allowed per module. on this line export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(withTranslation('common')(Footer))

Comment: You can only use default export on one item, in this case it's the function. You'll have to remove default export on the other props you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Hooks cant be used in class components, you can convert it to a functional component:

```
const Footer = () => {
    return (
         ...
    )
}
```

you can also leave it as class component:

```
class Footer extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
             show: false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you should create your function:

```
//add your imports
import { useState } from 'react';

//pass props if you're using prop drilling
function Footer(props) {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);
    return (
        <footer className="footer-bottom">
            <Container>
                <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
                    <Modal.Footer>
                        <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
                            Close
                        </Button>
                        <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
                            Save Changes
                        </Button>
                    </Modal.Footer>
                </Modal>
            </Container>
        </footer>
    );
}

//export the function
export default Footer;
```